# Javascript getelementbyId and add to it

Tags: javascript, math, addition, getelementbyid

This is probably going to be a very simple question, but javascript is very new to me and I really can't figure out why this isn't working.

I am building a shopping cart, and when the user selects their country to be outside of the UK then it will add a predefined shipping cost to the total. As default its set to 0.

So at the moment I am putting together a very simple function so that when the  box changes at all it adds 5 quid to the total (Im sure I can work out how to check for United Kingdom etc. afterwards).

So my javascript is this:

```
function checkPostageCost() {
    var grandTotal = document.getElementById("cartGrandTotal").value;
    var shippingTotal = 5;
    var newGrandTotal = grandTotal+shippingTotal;
    document.getElementById('invoiceGrandTotal').innerHTML = newGrandTotal;
}
```

The SELECT box:

```
<SELECT name='shippingForm_Country' id='shippingForm_Country' onChange="checkPostageCost();">
<?= $availableCountriesList ?>
</SELECT>
```

And its retrieving the grand total variable from a hidden input box like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cartGrandTotal" name="cartGrandTotal" value="<?= $finalGrandTotal ?>" />
```

If, for instance, my grand total is 5.49, then when it tries to add 5 to it it then becomes 5.495 - I obviously need it to become 10.49.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never ending story: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24383/16089 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to a number, e.g. by prefixing it with `+` or by using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). To avoid ugly numbers, convert it back to a string with two digits after the decimal point in the end using [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
function checkPostageCost() {
    var grandTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cartGrandTotal").value);
    var shippingTotal = 5;
    var newGrandTotal = grandTotal + shippingTotal;
    document.getElementById('invoiceGrandTotal').innerHTML = newGrandTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly.

In order for me to format the price I am using a php function displayAmount($amount).

How can I get this to work in javascript?

document.getElementById('invoiceGrandTotal').innerHTML = "<?= displayAmount(""+newGrandTotal.toFixed(2)+"") ?>";

Comment: You can't since PHP is server-side and JS is client-side.

Comment: Ok no worries I will find an alternative. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding them as strings and therefore it is just concatenating the two numbers one after another. Instead, convert them to `floats` and then do the adding and then back to string to do the `innerHTML` part:

`var grandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)`